# How to Create Named Range in VBA with Formula (Run-time error 438)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, named-ranges

I am trying to create a named range using VBA. Both `FirstBodyCell` and `ColumnCode` are single cells. I want the named range to eventually be defined as something that looks like this (depending on what column the `FirstBodyCell` is in):

```
=Offset(Sheet1!$E$8,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$E:$E)-COUNTA(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$7),1)
```

Using the sub below raises

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

and points to the line with `.Name = ColumnCode.Value`. Any idea on what is wrong with this code?

```
Sub CreateNamedRange(FirstBodyCell As Range, ColumnCode As Range)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Names
            .Name = "col_" & ColumnCode.Value
            .RefersToR1C1 = "=Offset(" & FirstBodyCell & ",0,0," & _
                          "COUNTA(" & Columns(FirstBodyCell.Column) & ")-COUNTA(" & _
                          Range(Cells(1, FirstBodyCell.Column), FirstBodyCell.Offset(-1, 0)) & _
                          "),1)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to return a address string not a range to the formula.  `Range(Cells(1, FirstBodyCell.Column), FirstBodyCell.Offset(-1, 0)).Address(1,1,xlR1C1)` and do the same with the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Workbook.Names` is a property that yields a `Names` collection class, which exposes members like `Add`, `Count`, `Parent`, and `Item`.

A `Names` object doesn't have a `Name` property, or a `RefersToR1C1` member (hence error 438 - member/property isn't supported/exposed by the object).

You want to invoke the `Add` member of that object - that function takes for parameters the values you're trying to assign there. Also, `.Address` will return an address that is not in R1C1 format. Try using `RefersTo` instead of `RefersToR1C1`.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add( _
    Name:="col_" & ColumnCode.Value, _
    RefersTo:="=Offset(" & FirstBodyCell & ",0,0," & _
                      "COUNTA(" & Columns(FirstBodyCell.Column) & ")-COUNTA(" & _
                      Range(Cells(1, FirstBodyCell.Column), FirstBodyCell.Offset(-1, 0)) & _
                      "),1)")
    'the With block variable is the Name object that was created+added to the Names collection:
    Debug.Print .Name
End With
```

Note [Scott Craner](https://superuser.com/questions/1455492/how-to-create-named-range-in-vba-with-formula-run-time-error-438#comment2195331_1455492) points out that you'll probably want to use the `.Address` of the `Range` objects you're supplying there, so the actual value for `RefersToR1C1` would be:

```
  RefersTo:="=Offset(" & FirstBodyCell & ",0,0," & _
                    "COUNTA(" & Columns(FirstBodyCell.Column).Address & ")-COUNTA(" & _
                    Range(Cells(1, FirstBodyCell.Column), FirstBodyCell.Offset(-1, 0)).Address & _
                    "),1)")
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the error. I am getting an error that says "The formula you typed contains an error." It is a 1004 error. I tried the code with and without `.Address` on FirstBodyCell. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Could be anything from mismatched parentheses (or double quotes) to a typo. Try defining the named range manually. Once you have it working, copy the working formula into your code. Cheers!

Comment: I had to use `RefersTo` instead of `RefersToR1C1`. Addresses aren't returned in R1C1 format. Thanks for your help!